# CAST failing to create date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting a cast failure and I can't fathom why.

Here's what is failing :

```
select cast('16/04/2012' as datetime)
```

The error is :

> "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range datetime value."

If I use `CONVERT` with a `103` for format it works without issue as you would expect.

The server is set to british date format, therefore the MSSQL account should also be defaulting to britsh format. It's been rebooted, so it shouldn't be that the service is using a different date format.

This is a SQL2005 instance.

What I really want to know is, what could be causing the CAST to fail?

Comment: What do you mean "the server" is set to British date format? The OS itself doesn't have a regional setting. Chances are, the admin account is using that format, and even the default setting for new accounts might be that format, but that doesn't mean the account under which the SQL service is running is using that format.  If it's an interactive account, log in an as that account and check regional settings.  Otherwise, check that account's registry hive to see what regional options are specified.

Comment: If at all possible, shift things around so that you use an unambiguous format (e.g. `20120416`), or ideally, avoid treating dates as strings all together.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '16/04/2012',105)
```

Comment: Actually, I think you want 103 for slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`?

Comment: You set me on the right path, when I run ... "select datepart(Month,'1/2/2000')" is shows the server is indeed returning the day for month.

Answer (score 0):

Date format and datetime format are not necessarily the same. While it may implicitly add the 00:00:00 for hh:mm:ss, maybe try adding that. Type 103 only includes dd/mm/yyyy, so it of course works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a data format as MM:dd:YY, and cast tries to convert you '16/04/2012' which is 'dd/MM/yy' and throws exception because 16 is less then 12 monthes.

You can either change your data format in [server settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx)  or use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) statement before your query

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the server is British language format?  If I run:

```
set language british
select cast('16/04/2012' as datetime)
```

Then I get:

> 2012-04-16 00:00:00.000

You can check the current session language with

```
select @@language
```

The session language defaults from the login in use, assuming it's a SQL Server-provisioned login (i.e. not a Windows user).  To check the language for a given user:

```
select loginproperty('myuser', 'DefaultLanguage')
```

To make a permanent server change for all newly created logins:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23
reconfigure
```

...where 23 is the `langid` obtained via `sp_helplanguage`.

Comment: don't forget to run `RECONFIGURE` after you change the language setting

Answer (score 0):

Always use a language neutral date format - it will always work regardless of any settings:

```
CAST('YYYYMMDD', AS DATE);
```

4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day and NO separators. You will never again have to worry about default language settings.